# cin, no output after entering required details

Tags: c++, netbeans, cin

I'm new to C++ and is trying to create a basic program in NetBeans. Below is the code I came up with:

```
int main() {

    unsigned scores[11] = {};
    unsigned grade;
    while (cin >> grade){
        if (grade <= 100){
            ++scores[grade/10];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << scores[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I entered a series of number

```
2 15 90 99 100
```

And pressed enter, the program is still running and no result is displayed. Why is this happening? Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `while(cin>>grade)` will keep reading until the end of all input. Try `ctrl+D`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send end of stream character, ctrl+d under UNIX and ctrl-z under windows. You can also restructure your code to read one line (until new line character) and then parse it:

```
unsigned scores[11] = {};
unsigned grade;
std::string line;
if (std::getline(cin, line)) {
    std::stringstream str(line);
    while (str >> grade) {
        if (grade <= 100) {
            ++scores[grade / 10];
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << scores[i] << endl;
}
```